# Inconsistent autocomplete behavior in LaTeX documents for strings containing underscores

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I’m having a problem with VSCode autocomplete in LaTeX documents: strings containing underscores don’t show up in the autocomplete menu in LaTeX (.tex) files, even though they do in plaintext (.txt) files (see screenshots). All relevant language-specific settings are identical as far as I can tell.

[image: Autocomplete menu in LaTeX]

[image: Autocomplete menu in plain text]

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved my proximate problem, which involves autocompleting reference labels containing underscores, by installing the [LaTeX Workshop extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop), which recognizes such labels (see attached). I’m still confused about the general case, but this is good enough for now.

[image]